# move lights with Move gizmo

Tags: 3d-view, interface, transforms, gizmo

Maybe I missed something or somehow changed a setting. I thought I could move lights with the move gizmo. Now I cannot move a point light or a camera with the move gizmo, all I can do is change the radius or the focal length. The gizmo does not allow the selection of the direction arrows. this is for any light type. I can move the lights with the G key but not the gizmo. If I changed a setting I have no idea what it was. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The direction arrows are the move gizmo.

Comment: Hello could you please show a screenshot of your whole interface?